# error: incompatible types: <anonymous Callback<List<UserDataResponse>>> cannot be converted to OnNoteListener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

What is the problem from this code?
I used Activity and passing it to fragment

RecyclerView OnClickListener the one i use in this coding method.

i just want to click the recyclerview to send me in to another page

Please help me right now :(

Here is my UsersAdapter

```
public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UsersViewHolder> {
private Context mCtx;
private ArrayList<UserDataResponse> userDataResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
private OnNoteListener mOnNoteListener;


public UsersAdapter(Context mCtx, ArrayList<UserDataResponse> userDataResponseList, OnNoteListener 
onNoteListener) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.userDataResponseList = userDataResponseList;
    this.mOnNoteListener = onNoteListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.recycle_view, parent, false);

    return new UsersAdapter.UsersViewHolder(view, mOnNoteListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersAdapter.UsersViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.textViewName.setText("Username: " + userDataResponseList.get(position).getRTMusername());
    holder.textViewEmail.setText("Firstname: " + userDataResponseList.get(position).getRTMfirstname());
    holder.textViewLastname.setText("Lastname: " + userDataResponseList.get(position).getRTMlastname());
    holder.textViewDepartment.setText("Department: " + userDataResponseList.get(position).getRTMdepartment());




}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return userDataResponseList.size();
}

class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView textViewName,textViewEmail,textViewLastname,textViewDepartment;
    OnNoteListener onNoteListener;

    public UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnNoteListener onNoteListener) {

        super(itemView);

        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        textViewLastname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLastname);
        textViewDepartment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDepartment);
        this.onNoteListener = onNoteListener;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onNoteListener.onNoteClick(getAdapterPosition());

    }
}
public interface OnNoteListener{
    void onNoteClick(int postion);
}
}
```

And here is my AdminUser.java

```
public class AdminUserFragment extends Fragment implements UsersAdapter.OnNoteListener {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private UsersAdapter adapter;
Api api;

 ArrayList<String> Userdata;
 ArrayList<UserDataResponse> userDataResponseArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
 Redirectinglog redirectinglog;
private Handler refresherHandler = new Handler();

public AdminUserFragment() {

}
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adminuser,container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Userdata = new ArrayList<>();
    redirectinglog = new Redirectinglog(getActivity());

    api = RetrofitClientInstance.GetResultAPI().create(Api.class);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    refreshRunnable.run();






}
private  void responseuserdata(){

    Call<List<UserDataResponse>> usercall = api.getUsers();

    usercall.enqueue(new Callback<List<UserDataResponse>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<UserDataResponse>> call, Response<List<UserDataResponse>> response) {

            userDataResponseArrayList = new ArrayList<>(response.body());

            for(UserDataResponse UserDataResponsetest :  userDataResponseArrayList){

                adapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(), userDataResponseArrayList, this);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<UserDataResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

private Runnable refreshRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        responseuserdata();
        refresherHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
};


@Override
public void onNoteClick(int postion) {

}
}
```

What should I use?
Help me please huhuh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
adapter = new UsersAdapter(getActivity(), userDataResponseArrayList, this);
```

Here you are passing an anonymous class instead of passing an object whose class implements onNoteListener interface. Thats why, there is a problem of compatability."this corresponds to an anonymous class because you are calling it from an anonymous class which is passed it as a parameter of Usercall.enque.

My suggestion to you would be instead of creating all that mess, you can simply set a tag in your onbindViewHolder with the position being passed and whenever user taps on the recycler view , you can check it on onClick method which you will be having if you just wire an Onclicklistener to the recycler view.You can retreive the tag value from the row in question and find out which position was clicked.Simple and easy.Comment down if you have any trouble undertsanding in what i said, i will write the code sample as well.Hope my answer helps,if it helps please mark it as accepted.Cheers.

create a view in your UserViewHolderClass as a member variable and inside the constructor of this "ViewHolderClass" write this.view = view, to assign row value to it.

```
//inside onBindViewholder class, write
MyViewHolder.view.setTag("position")
        MyHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = view.getTag("position")// this will give you 
                                              //the position of the row which will be tapped
            }
        });
```

Also, if you will create a member value view, yo dont need to keep the other member variable in the text view,in your onCreateViewHolder, you can simplydo view.findviewid("pass id of textview, image view whatever you have in your row ans you wanna find) and get the appropriate widget present as element in your row.This is because this view will have all your text views, image views whatever you have used in row's xml file.

Comment: Okay i will wait for it

Comment: Ohhh i get it. Thank you so mucch, you are lifesaveerr